# How to change UITabBar Selection color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I need to change the selection color of UITabBar from default blue to red. How do we do this.

Answer (score 60):

**Update September 2017:**
It's been two years since I've written this answer and since it's receiving upvotes regularly, I should say this is probably the worst possible answer to this question, it's error prone, likely to break because of iOS updates, hard to debug, etc., so please don't do the things I've written and apply better solutions such as subclassing UITabBar or UITabBarController. Thanks.

You can do this by setting a "tintColor" attribute (Key Path) for you UITabBar.

1. Select the UITabBar in the document outline. (**NOT** the Controller with the yellow icon.)
2. Select Identity Inspector in the Utilities area.
3. Click the + in "User Defined Runtime Attributes."
4. Add a "tintColor" Key Path of type "Color" and the color you want.

This should do it. You can check it against the screenshot below.

[image]

**More on this:**
There's a "Tint" attribute in Identity Inspector of UITabBar which I believed would do the exact same thing but apparently, it does nothing. It's default value is the exact default fill color when a UITabBarItem is selected, so my guess is it would be fixed in the stable release Xcode 7. Fingers crossed.

Comment: you can do this on xcode 6 too, good answer, this should be the solution

Comment: seems like this still isn't fixed in the official release of xcode 7 - this answer saved me some headache, thank you!

Answer (score 19):

In IOS5, UITabBar has a [selectedImageTintColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor) property which does what you need.

Comment: @KPM, I see it's deprecated, but what should we use instead? This is still working on iOS 8, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 15):

In iOS 7 it's simply the tintColor. One way to accomplish this could be to subclass UITabBarViewController, set the custom class in the storyboard, and in your `viewDidLoad` method of the subclassed tabBarVC add this:

```
[[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I constantly as my self: "Why do I have to create a subclass for such a minor thing like changing colors?". Good question, why the f* don't simply automatically inherit the tintColor from the parent view? And why doesn't the interface builder setting don't do nothing?

Comment: How to use SelectedImageTintColor in ios 8

Comment: [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; would also do the trick.

Comment: and if you want to set the color for the unselected text it's `unselectedItemTintColor`

Answer (score 15):

[image]

To achieve above result perform following steps.

**Step 1:** Add your desired images in `Assets.xcassets`, and make sure they `Render As`: `Default`

[image]

**Step 2:** Select your `UITabBar` object and set `Image Tint` color, this color will be selected tab color

[image]

**Step 3:** Select `UITabBar` object and add **Key Path**: `unselectedItemTintColor`, **Type**: `Color`, **Value**: `Choose color for unselected item` in **User Defined Runtime Attributes**.

[image]

All done.

Comment: Thumbs up bro!!

Answer (score 11):

It is extremely easy

Create a custom class of **UITabBarController** and in `-(void)viewDidLoad` method add this line:

```
[[self tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: but this will change color of Text, not the entire selection area. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

Because UITextAttributeTextColor is deprecated in iOS 7, you should use:

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor purpleColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting from iOS 8 it's as simple as:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply change the following property in Interface Builder for the TabBar

[image]

Obviously in my case its White.

Answer (score 4):

The SDK does not make this easy, but it is *technically* possible.  Apple apparently believes this to be part of their vision of a consistent look and feel.

UITabBar is a subclass of UIView.  You can always subclass and implement your own `-drawRect:`

This is not a trivial task, however, you have to essentially re-implement the class from scratch or you risk some weird side-effects.

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 5 Programatically

It is pretty easy in Swift 5.

In your `TabBarController` write this:

```
tintColor = UIColor.red
```

That's it

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for a way to set the selected text color of a UITabBarItem and have found a dead simple method, using the UIAppearance protocol.

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor purpleColor] }     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Please excuse the awful colors!

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor is deprecated. whats the alternative?

Comment: I think it is NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5.0 fixes this issue but the solution is under NDA. Look up UITabBar in your documentation for an EASY way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest solution -

1. Select Tab Bar in Tab Bar Controller
2. Set Image Tint color
3. Set Tint Color

For reference see the attached image.

[image]