# Tabbar with custom colors

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to create a Tabbar application.My basic necessity is that i want the color of tab bar icons to be red instead of the default blue color.(i.e the selected tab icon has to be of red color instead of the default blue color provided by apple).I dont want the color of the tab bar to be changed.I want it to be of the default black color.Hope the question makes sense.

I want the tab bar to look something like this

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790746/how-to-change-uitabbar-selection-color ?

Comment: Yes i have referred to that link but i am not getting a solution there.

Answer (score 2):

As nicktmro noted, you have to customize everything.

Check this previous answer:
[Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar)
(check a couple of answers on this one, a later answer fixes problems with the accepted answer)

And this blog post:
[iPhone TabBar Custom Background Image](http://duivesteyn.net/2010/01/16/iphone-custom-tabbar-background-image/)

---

**ADDED**

Here's another one that looks clean and easy:

[Custom colors in UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)

Be sure to read the comment on the answer.

Comment: Hey but that class is a private class.We are not permitted to use private classes and methods.ri8?

Comment: I'll add another link now that looks very clean and doesn't seem to use anything off limits. I know it can be done because a friend completely recolored the whole interface and never used private methods.

Comment: Hey guys these all links provide the color change of the tab bar itself.I want to change the color of the selected icon to be red instead of blue

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own "tab bar" controller. Unfortunately the "blue" color you are talking about is actually just an alpha level, not a shade of blue.