# iPhone UITabBarItem two lines title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lines, uitabbaritem

I have to set a title, which is a bit long, in a UITabBarItem; so the question is:

Is it possible to set a title which has two lines in a UITabBarItem?

I have tried the following way (but it does not work):

```
UITabBarItem* myTabBarItem = ... //Allocation and initialization -via Objective-C code or Interface Builder-
myTabBarItem.title = @"Hello\nHello";
```

However, the text (title) that I can see at the bottom of the UITabBarItem is
"Hello Hello" (that is the two "Hello's" are placed in one line) instead of "Hello\nHello" (one hello in one line and the other in another line).

Thanks,

Comment: i think if you want to multiline title of Tabbar title then customize toolbar use for this.... its better.. :)

Answer (score -2):

Check the following Links(Most of the customization of the tab-bar controller)

1. [Implement a Custom Tab Bar](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)
2. [Tabbar with custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343764/tabbar-with-custom-colors)
3. [RKTabView - ready to use solution](https://github.com/RafaelKayumov/RKTabView)
4. [RX-Tabbar controller](http://www.rumex.it/2011/07/hiding-your-new-custom-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application/)
5. [Custom tabbar](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)

Best Regards,