# How to make multiple color tab bar in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've been trying to find the solution to this for the last week, and I have had no luck after trying every possible solution I could find or think of. Every solution I found and have attempted has not worked.

I have 4 UITabBarItem's in a UITabBar placed within UITabBarController. I want to put individual background color (OR image) of the UITabBarItem. Screen shot is attached [image]

I am using Swift, and iOS SDK 9.3 in Xcode 8.0. If you can only answer in Objective-C that is fine too, any answer will help! Thank you all in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: put individual tab color its batter but if you want to set color in shades then its create problem with individual tab effect .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya. thanks!. but how to put individual tab color?

Comment: to set individual tab color from storyboard . on select and default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that -at least- one of the following links to be useful to your case:

1. [Creating a Custom Tab Bar](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar).
2. [Tabbar with custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343764/tabbar-with-custom-colors).
3. [iOS Custom UI Series: TabBar & NavBar](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios-custom-ui-series-tabbar-navbar/).
4. [iOS TUTORIAL: Creating a custom tabbar using Storyboard in
   Xcode](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/).
5. [RXCustomTabBar](https://github.com/faroligo/RXCustomTabBar).
6. [iOS custom tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345426/ios-custom-tabbar).
7. [How to create custom tab bar in Swift](http://blog.adambardon.com/how-to-create-custom-tab-bar-in-swift-part-1/).

Comment: I will check and let you know if its solve my problem. Thank you for help

Comment: Link number 1 help me `Thanks!`

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass the uitabbarcontroller and in this class in the viewDidLoad function add a views with background colors and imageViews with these icons to this view and make the view userInteractionEnabled = false